# my jquery code does not seem to work in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jquery code is not working on my html file.

I linked it to my html file with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.overlay.js"></script>
```

which I think is the correct way to connect it. The address, I'm sure, is correct as well.

The jquery is supposed to hide my `div` `class="modal"` when `$(document).ready()`, but it is not working..

Is it possible that the `jQuery` can not recognize if document is ready? What could I have done wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6yspgcdx/

Comment: well who is gonna add the jquery library http://jsfiddle.net/x0fbaye5/

Comment: you did not included jQuery in your fiddle check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6yspgcdx/1/

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand the question.. i can see that you've fixed it for me. can you tell what i have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Actually The jquery.min.js is missing,

And, then you have given

```
$('.overlay').hide();
```

And, the next line you have given click function, If the element is hide means, how the click function can trigger.

```
$('.overlay').click(function () {
```

As same

```
 $('.content').hide();
```

But written click function in

```
$('#f1no1').click(function(){
```

The f1no1 id is children of content.

Comment: yep. i'm sorry i haven't fixed that yet. but $('.overlay').hide(); is not working.

Comment: jquery.min.js is missing. you should include js in your html. <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In Js fiddle, The side bar few things are available. The name of "Frameworks & Extensions" you have to select Js. (version as your wish ex:jquery 1.9.1)

Comment: ^ this! this worked..

Comment: okay leonardpcs08 :)